# Flask {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }} returns nothing

Tags: python, flask

I was having issues with a js script not running in my Flask app and found that the root path was nothing. After that, i setup a simple test page like this:

```
@app.route('/test')
def index2():
        return render_template('test.html')
```

test.html:

```
{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}
```

And it just prints:

```
""
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ins't the `script_root` empty because you are directly on the root of that server?

From [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/):

> Do you know where your application is? If you are developing the
>   answer is quite simple: it’s on localhost port something and directly
>   on the root of that server.

```
@app.route('/test')
def index2():
    if not request.script_root:
        # this assumes that the 'index' view function handles the path '/'
        request.script_root = url_for('index', _external=True)

    return render_template('test.html')
```

test.html:

```
{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}
```

Renders:

```
"http://localhost:5000/"
```